# Headphones don't work correctly on an Asus k50ij laptop

Tags: 11.04, soundcard

I have asus k50ij series laptop and runung dual os on it. On windows instalation everything works great, but then ubuntu is being used headphones and speakers works at the same time or both gets muted. i have googled for solution but found any working fixes. How to get my sound card working as it should?

Answer (score 1):

Here someone have fixed it on a K60I, and it seems to work on my ASUS K50IJ too:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1762969

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.